# how to test a series of transformations in osb

Tags: xquery, osb

I have the following problem: I'm making a request to external system using OSB. External system gives me a response and I would like to make a series of transformations with it. How can I test this series of transformations of a response?

Basically, I would like to write an XML response by hand, apply all transformations (in bulk) and get the result. So, I don't create a mock of an external service and start with a request, since I would like to test only the response part - whether my transformations are valid and are working properly.

[Here is the screenshot of my message flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sD4bV.jpg) The part I would like to test is in yellow.

Thank you!

Comment: With transformations, you mean xqueries? You can test those one by one.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a separate callable pipeline that includes only the response transformations. 
Then you would be able to test it by calling it from the service bus console